# How to post multiple images to a FB page using the javascript API?

Tags: api, facebook

Im trying to post to a Facebook page with multiple images as attached_media.
But this is posting 2 different posts with only one image in each and not one post with 3 images.
So I guess the problem is the `attached_media` somehow?

I first make 2 post with `published : false` and then Im posting with the below.

I know that fotoid1 and fotoid2 gets the right photoid number from the 2 first posts.

```
var attached_media;
    attached_media=   [{media_fbid: fotoid1},{media_fbid: fotoid2}]
                        
    FB.api('/' + pageId + '/feed', 'post', {
            message :facebooktexten,
            url : bildUrl,
            published : true,
            attached_media: attached_media,
            access_token : aToken 
            }, function(response) {     
                if (!response || response.error) {      
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    console.log('response'+response.error)          
                } else {                        
                    console.log('Photo ID: ' + response.id);
                    console.log('Post ID: ' + response.post_id);                            
                }
    });
```

So what Im I missing here? Any input really appreciated, thanks.

SOLVED-so the answer is to first send a request with the images to pageId/photos and then send a pageId/feed request with the ids you get back from the photos request in the attached_media.

Comment: Wrong endpoint. You want to create a post, so it is not `/pageid/photos`, but `/pageid/feed`

Comment: Thanks Cbroe, but I have set /pageid/feed for all three requests and I get an error: An unknown error has occurred. I also tested to set endpoint to /pageid/photos for the first 2 and /pageid/feed for the last posting one, but no luck. Im getting Photo ID1: 100492555128800_247205443790843 and Photo ID2: 100492555128800_247205440457510 when I send the 2 first to pageId/feed, but if I send tp pageid/photos then I get Photo ID1: 247205443790843, Photo ID2:247205440457510 without the pageid.

Comment: `100492555128800_247205443790843` is the ID of the post _about_ your photo upload, `247205443790843` is the ID of the photo object itself. You need to use the latter in your 3rd request to /page/feed.

Comment: Yes I need to post to pageid/photos in the 2 first ones and use those imageids and post to pageid/feed in the lats one. I got it working now, however it is only showing the 2 attached images not the one that is specified by url:'someimage.jpg' in the last request. Maybe thats the way it suppose to work? That it only shows the attached ones? Also, what is the difference if I post a single image to /photos or /feed the post looks exactly the same when posted? THANKS A LOT CBroe ;-)